# Received error after entering 'brew doctor'

Tags: homebrew, macos-catalina, brew-doctor

I'm new to programming and this question may seem pretty easy...so please bear with me.

After I entered 'brew doctor' in the terminal, instead of prompting something like 'Your system is ready to brew', I got the following:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6-config
```

From my shallow understanding, am I supposed to delete one of the python versions or keep both and enter another command to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew is telling you that the 5 files:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6-config
```

are not installed by Homebrew and can confuse him. If you don't use Python versions installed outside Homebrew, you can delete these files and the `brew doctor` command should again display:

```
Your system is ready to brew.
```

Comment: Hi Ortomala, thanks for the reply. Following the path I didn't find python 3.8 I installed under the 'Versions' file, instead the file shows two folders - 3.7 and current - both containing the same files. None of which has the listed files except for python3-config. 

I'm sure I installed python 3.8, which the system has already shown in the error. Am I looking at the wrong place..?

Comment: These 5 files are probably residual files or residual links from previous installation. You can delete them from the terminal, one by one, with the `rm` command. For the first file run `rm /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3-config`, do the same for the next files.